# xymatrix: How to change the position of a vertex?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I have the following simple diagram:

```
\[
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d] \\
C \ar[r]        & Dxxx = Exxx = Fxxx}
\]
```

which will be typeset so that `B` will have a down arrow, possibly pointing to the `Exxx` part, as the `Dxxx = Exxx = Fxxx` node is really long. However, I want to typeset it so that it has the same structure (arrow length, node positioning) as

```
\[
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d] \\
C \ar[r]        & D}
\]
```

with the extra `xxx = Exxx = Fxxx` part following `D` in the last node.

How do I do that? I remember seeing this in some guide but cannot find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shift a node to the right by enclosing it in braces and preceding it with `*+[r]`.  Thus, if you type

```
\[
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d] \\
C \ar[r]        & *+[r]{Dxxx = Exxx = Fxxx}}
\]
```

then you'll get

[image]

This is described in section 8.3 of the amslatex-primer at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amslatex-primer